# I have an error while I try a "benchmark" on gnome disks utility

Tags: mount, hard-drive, gnome-disk-utility

I have a problem with disks. When I try to test the velocity of my hard drive, the system show me a message that says "error unmounting /dev/sda2: target is busy (udisks-error-quark,14)", but it's only when I put the write option too. I only have ubuntu in my laptot. 
Thank you every one.
PD:sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely expected - you can't run write benchmark from GNOME Disks on the mounted and system drive.

Write benchmark will work only for unmounted and non-system drive. It needs access to the whole drive (from zero sector to its end).

If you want to run full (read and write) benchmark internal drive of your laptop - boot from LiveCD/USB and run GNOME Disks from it.

Comment: Thank you so much!